# see wrong classification in confusion matrix

Tags: python, scikit-learn, text-classification

```
  from IPython.display import display
    #print( df["topic"].factorize().CategoricalIndex)
    #df["topic"].factorize()
    for predicted in df["topic"].factorize()[0]:
       for actual in df["topic"].factorize()[0]:
         if predicted != actual and conf_mat[actual, predicted] >= 10:
           print("'{}' predicted as '{}' : {} examples.".format(topics[actual],topics[predicted], conf_mat[actual, predicted]))
           display(df.loc[indices_test[(y_test == actual) & (pred == predicted)]][['topic', 'body_wakati']])
           print('')
```

I want to see the wrong classification from confusion matri by iterate all data in dataframe, but it produce same data over and over again, is there something wrong with the code?

[image: pic]

this is the df data and indices test

[image]

Comment: pandas factorize returns labels and uniques, and with df["topic"].factorize()[0],  you are iterating over labels, which are repeating.  Try to change this to df["topic"].factorize()[1], then you will iterate over unique values, this should solve the problem.

Comment: @AnnaK. Thankyou so much but it now it gave "IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices" in  `if predicted != actual and conf_mat[actual, predicted] >= 10:`  , is the unique not return number?

Comment: unique does not return numpy array if your data is not numpy array, you can see documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html .  Since you need integers, you could try to substitute df["topic"].factorize()[0] with np.unique(df["topic"].factorize()[0]), to avoid repetitions.

Comment: @AnnaK.  Thankyou , I see that unique return categoricalindex and categories but is there a way to convert categoricalindex to numpy array to iterate over it?